# How to improve Performance of Angular 5 *nFor Loop which using long Array

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using ngFor for rendering big Array which has 100 items and each item has own 20 item. Array's interface below:

```js
export interface DataRowModel {
  row_id: string,
  row_number: number,
  columns: ColumnModel[],
  isNew: boolean;
}

export interface ColumnModel {
  column_id: string,
  value: string,
  label: string,
  isSelected: boolean
}
```

I'm using array in below:

```html
<div #dataTable
     class="data-table"
     [ngStyle] ="data_table_style"
     (scroll)="handleDataTableScroll($event)">

  <div class="data-row"
       *ngFor="let oneRow of data; trackBy: getRowTrackById; let row_index = index;"
       [class.dark]="(row_index %2) == 0"
       [ngStyle] ="data_row_style">

    <div class="row-number" 
      [ngStyle] ="data_row_number_style">
      <p class="row-number">{{oneRow.row_number}}</p>
    </div>


      <ng-template 
        ngFor let-oneColumn 
        [ngForOf]="oneRow.columns" 
        let-column_index="index">
        <div
          #selectedDivRef
          class="data-column"
          [class.selected]="oneColumn.isSelected"
          (click)="columnClicked(oneRow.row_id, column_index)">

          <p
            *ngIf="!oneColumn.isSelected"
            class="one-data">
            {{oneColumn | declaration}}
          </p>

          <input
            #editingInputTextRef
            onlyNumberDirective
            [isNumeric]="isEditingInputNumeric"
            [isDecimal]="true"
            [decimalCount]="0"
            class="columnInput"
            *ngIf="oneColumn.isSelected"
            type="text" 
            [(ngModel)]="editingInputText" />

          <!--[autoFocus]="isInputFocused"-->

        </div>

      </ng-template>

  </div>

</div>
```

```js
  getRowTrackById(index, dataRow: DataRowModal) {
    return dataRow.row_id;
  }
```

```js
public data_row_number_style = {
  left: "0"
};

....
....

ngOnInit() {
    this.dataTableElement = this.dataTableRef.nativeElement;
    this.variableTableElement = this.variableTableRef.nativeElement;
    this.setHeight();
    this.setWidth();
  }
  
  
....
....

handleDataTableScroll($event) {
    if (this.dataTableElement.scrollLeft > 0) {
      this.variableTableElement.scrollLeft = this.dataTableElement.scrollLeft;
      this.data_row_number_style.left = this.dataTableElement.scrollLeft + "px";
    }
  }
```

When all columns are empty, UI is fluid. But when %50-60 of columns are filled with data, UI lacks, input slow downs and scrolling becomes Glitchy. I added trackBy function but it doesn't affect so much. I hold whole data in service. In the contructor of component I get data from service. Update and Delete operations handled in service too. How can i improve ngFor loop performance?

Comment: Pagination is your best bet.

Comment: I use Excel like table interface unfortunately I can't use pagination

Comment: If the problem is when you scroll, ngFor is probably not the problem. The problem is with the scroll event handler, which is called a lot, and which, at the very least, causes a change detection cycle for each scroll event. What is this event handler used for? What is its code? Try removing it, and see what happens.

Comment: I updated question with handleDataTableScroll() function. Input slowed down too.